# Database insertion codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I was working on a project and here's the code,the problem is that I want to add the $newRapport array values (VIS_MATRICULE, RAP_NUM) also in $newMedicament.
    if(isset($_POST['add_rapport'])){

```
$newRapport = array (//'VIS_MATRICULE'=>$this->input->post('VIS_MATRICULE'), 
                'VIS_MATRICULE'=>$_POST['VIS_MATRICULE'],
            'RAP_NUM'=> '',
            'PRA_NUM'=>$_POST['PRA_NUM'],
            'RAP_DATE'=>$_POST['RAP_DATE'],
            'RAP_BILAN'=>$_POST['RAP_BILAN'],
            'RAP_MOTIF'=>$_POST['RAP_MOTIF']);
                 $this->db->insert('rapport_visite', $newRapport);

         // Pour Les Composants

                       //Pour les Médicaments                      
$newMedicament = array ('VIS_MATRICULE'=>$_POST['VIS_MATRICULE'],
                        'RAP_NUM'=> '',
                        'MED_DEPOTLEGAL'=>$_POST['MED_DEPOTLEGAL'],
                        'OFF_QTE'=>$_POST['OFF_QTE']) ;
                 $this->db->insert('offrir', $newMedicament);

        }
```

the problem is that it says:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`swissvisite`.`offrir`, CONSTRAINT `offrir_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`VIS_MATRICULE`, `RAP_NUM`) REFERENCES `rapport_visite` (`VIS_MATRICULE`, `RAP_NUM`))

INSERT INTO `offrir` (`VIS_MATRICULE`, `RAP_NUM`, `MED_DEPOTLEGAL`, `OFF_QTE`) VALUES ('a131', '', 'EVILR7', '2')

Filename: C:\wamp\www\code\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Comment: this question is not clear.

Comment: I cannot add the two values in $newMedicament it says database error that's what the problem is

Comment: still not clear. edit your question and make it clear

Comment: @user3410718: Please reject my editing. As you already do it.

Comment: okay thanks for the edit by the way.

Comment: Make sure the values you are inserting are already exisintg in the parent table.

Comment: Can't I do the insertion of both tables at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

1.Well it looks like your table swissvisite is breaking a constraint offrir_ibfk_2. You understand that foreign key constraits rely on data integrity. You cannot update TableA(swissvisite) unless (VIS_MATRICULE`,`RAP_NUM) exists in rapport_visite table for the record you are inserting into swissvisite.

2.Also Looks like you are doing this in the controller: this is incorrect:

Load the model in you construct:

```
     public function __construct()
           {
                parent::__construct();

            $this->load->model('mymodel');


           }

  public function myfunction()
{
$myarray  = $_POST['mydata'];
//call your model
$this->mymodel->insert_into_db($myarray);


}


}
```

lastly please don't do NOT pass $_POST data directly into your query, bind it to variables and pass those in.

Comment: Okay thanks edward is there no way to insert both of them at the same time? i will make the changes immediately.

Comment: Insert your record into the table rapport_visite table first. Then update your other table.